# Wifi [ath9k] not working on 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 14.04

It's work on Debian 7 but not on ubuntu how do I fix it. I can't enable it.

```
rfkill unblock all
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

lsmod | grep -E 'ath|brcmsmac'
ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              626489  1 ath9k
cfg80211              484040  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
ath3k                  13318  0 
bluetooth             395423  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm

dmesg | grep -E 'cfg|ath|wlan'
[    0.930410] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 00a5a65759de474bc5c43120880c1b94a539f431'
[    9.291368] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    9.300678] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    9.320226] ath: phy0: Disable PLL PowerSave
[    9.328827] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[    9.328831] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[    9.328832] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    9.328834] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    9.328835] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[    9.454629] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    9.454633] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    9.454634] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.454636] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.454638] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.454639] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.454640] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   10.225331] SKU: Nid=0x1d sku_cfg=0x40e5812d
[   10.225566] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x40e5812d for NID 0x1d
[   13.027048] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   23.211611] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   86.586843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  277.391415] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  290.307430] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  293.017900] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  475.096690] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Comment: "Soft blocked: yes" did you tried unblocking it?

Comment: Yes, but it's can't.

Comment: Could you please paste the output of you trying?

Comment: rfkill unblock all and result is acer-wireless: Wireless LAN still Soft blocked: yes others no

Comment: [edit] your question instead. Also, did you tried 13.10?

Comment: No, this nb used Debian 7.

Comment: This was a work around that worked for me on an ASUS r510c http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My nb is Asus K450J just type
`echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
and everything fine.
credit: varunendra - ubuntu member

Answer (score 0):

I can report the same after upgrading to 14.04.

I've noticed that in the upgrade a new kernel version was installed (`3.13.0-something`), and in `/lib/modules/3.13-something/` the `ath9k` is missing.  I don't know where it is supposed to be.

When I boot the `3.8.0-somethong kernel`, the drivers work again.